# Refreshing metadata on user functions t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am doing some T-SQL programming and I have some Views defines on my database. The data model is still changing these days and I have some table functions defined. Sometimes i deliberately use

```
 select * from MYVIEW
```

in such a table function to return all columns. If the view changes (or table) the function crashes and I need to recompile it. I know it is in general good thing so that it prevents from hell lotta errors but still...

Is there a way to write such functions so the dont' blow up in my face everytime I change something on the underlying table? Or maybe I am doing something completely wrong...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define views as "WITH SCHEMABINDING"

And I'll refer you to my answer here which covers similar stuff...

[“select * from table” vs “select colA,colB,etc from table” interesting behaviour in SqlServer2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321468/select-from-table-vs-select-cola-colb-etc-from-table-interesting-behaviour/323103#323103)

In this case, the problem is not the udf but how views behave without SCHEMABINDING

Edit: Cade Roux's sp_refreshsqlmodule might do the trick. I've never used it.

Comment: I do not believe that this achieves his objective.  He is wanting to alter tables that are used in views with select *. 

Read the following from MSDN
SCHEMABINDING
[...]In addition, ALTER TABLE statements on tables that participate in views having schema binding will fail if these statements affect the view definition.

I think this is exactly the behavior that luckyluke does not desire.

Comment: @doug_w: hobson's choice: use WITH SCHEMABINDING or run sp_refreshview every time. No alternatives. You may also want to read my other answer where I quoted the same link. FYI, I use SCHEMABINDING in all my views and udfs.

Answer (score 3):

[gbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454763/refreshing-metadata-on-user-functions-t-sql/2454821#2454821) is best - but when you have SCHEMABINDING, this often prevents you from making underlying changes without first removing SCHEMABINDING and then replacing it when recreating the module.  You can't use SCHEMABINDING if your object references objects outside the database.

If this difficulty is so great you don't wish to or can't use SCHEMABINDING, then using [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) in some kind of regular process which you run to check your SQL modules for errors before they actually are used (it can be run on any non-schemabound view, UDF, stored proc, etc) is your friend.

You can use both techniques together - you cannot (and there is no need to) run sp_refreshsqlmodule against schemabound objects.

e.g., you can only run it on these modules:

```
SELECT *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        WHERE   (
                 OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(ROUTINE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ROUTINE_NAME)), N'IsSchemaBound') IS NULL
                 OR OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(ROUTINE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ROUTINE_NAME)),
                                   N'IsSchemaBound') = 0
                )
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed because I only use SCHEMABINDING. Useful.

Comment: @gbn - I use SCHEMABINDING when I can, but it doesn't work across databases (and rightly so) and it can only work on top of other schemabound object - if any object in a chain cannot be schemabound, your use of SCHEMABINDING comes to an end right there.  In this case, breaking external changes can be adequately monitored with sp_refreshsqlmodule before they will actually break anything.  sp_refreshsqlmodule will cause extended properties to be lost on table-valued UDFs in SQL Server 2005 (but this already happens when you ALTER them to remove and re-add SCHEMABINDING).