# SQL Server Views - INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

When I query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` it lists all views, but when I query  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE` it displays only a few views.

How can I rebuild all the views info in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the entire database as a script (right click database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts).  Running that script in a new database will generate the correct dependencies.  You can then pump over the data from the old database.  I'd expect that to be a lot of work.

There are commercial tools, like [RedGate SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_tracker/index.htm), that make this much easier.  They have a free demo, but be warned, you'll grow dependent on those tools quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) or [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) on non-schemabound views.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454763/refreshing-metadata-on-user-functions-t-sql)