# How can I get the view to display the current column definition?

Tags: sql-server, view, schema

Using SQL Server Express 2008 & Management Studio.

I have a table & a view. At the time the View was created, the Table's FirstName column was varchar(50). Modify Table.Firstname to be nvarchar(50) and the View still indicates that the column is varchar(50).

How do I get the View to display the current column definition?

Here's what I've tried (that didn't work):

- Click the Refresh button
- Close Management Studio & re-open it.

Here's what did work:

- Create a brand new view. The new view does display the current field definition

Note: This project has many views, so I'd prefer not to have to re-create all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule in Books Online.

Comment: Thanks! In this particular case, sp_refreshsqlmodule works well for views that were created w/o "WITH SCHEMABINDING".
e.g. EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'myDatabase.dbo.myView1'

Answer (score 4):

Run either [sp_refreshview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) or the newer [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx)

The best solution is to use [`WITH SCHEMABINDING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) so this can't happen.

Quite common on SO, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321468/select-from-table-vs-select-cola-colb-etc-from-table-interesting-behaviour/323103#323103)