# TSQL select all columns from join with same names

Tags: t-sql, join

If I have a query

```
select * into #tmp1 from dbo.t1  inner join dbo.t2  on t1.Sender_Id=t2.Id
```

I get an error

`Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Id' in table '#tmp1' is specified more than once`.

How can I do the same thing without resorting to

```
select t1.Id as t1id, t1.col2. ... t1.col30, t2.Id as t2id, ... t2.col40 as t2col40 from ...
```

notation.

I just need to quickly and manualy examine several tables, so I'd like to have a quick way of examining joins.

Comment: Unfortunately if there are duplicate columns you need to resolve that when using `SELECT * INTO`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT \* but without "Column names must be unique in each view"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423684/how-to-select-but-without-column-names-must-be-unique-in-each-view)

Comment: As already mentioned. You can't. You will need to specify the column names and ensure they are unique. However, rather than using 'SELECT * INTO'. You could explicitly create the table beforehand (with unique column names) and do an 'INSERT INTO' instead. This allows you to use SELECT * still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to persist the result via `select * into #tmp` or want to create a view, every field name has to be unique and you will have to uses aliases for fields with identical names.
A simple query does not need unique names.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, columns name must unique in select statement, in your case, you have for example two (02) id, one from tbl1, and the other one from tbl2, on esolution is list them as:

`Select t1.id, t2.id
From tbl1 as t1 Inner Join tbl2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id`

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Or, if you have columns with same name in both tables, use this:

```
Select t1.*, t2.* From tbl1 as t1 Inner join tbl2 as t2 On t1.id = t2.id
```

Regards