# Use join column only once in SELECT *

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose:

```
WITH t12 AS (SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id))
SELECT * FROM t12
```

This will fail with:

```
The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 't12'.
```

Now this is a large query as `t1` and `t2` have many (+200) columns. I am not to list them all: I explicitly want to use the `*`.

Normally I would solve this with the `USING (id)` clause, but SQL Server doesn't seem to support that. Any ideas?

Other option is to work without the `WITH` clause -- which *works* but makes the code less readable.

*There are many answers on SO that make you list all fields. This is an explicit question to do it without, in the WITH clause and in pure SQL. Related questions like "exclusion fields" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except) and one [for views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423684/how-to-select-but-without-column-names-must-be-unique-in-each-view) ask for non-ANSI SQL capabilities. This question is targeted for pure SQL and would be possible (as far as I understand) if SQL Server supported [ANSI SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join) syntax.*

Comment: "This is an explicit question to do it without." - you can't

Comment: @MartinSmith, Ok thanks. I'll leave it unanswered, until things change.

Comment: Is creating the SQL dynamically (either directly in T-SQL or in your client language of choice) an option?

Comment: @Heinzi, thanks, but no. This is an explicit SQL question.

Comment: @DavorJosipovic: OK. Then I *think* you're out of options, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I suppose you need it to work within a CTE for something, because with just the SELECT from the CTE alone it shouldn't be an issue to use *.

Comment: But a select within a CTE or subquery must return unique columnnames. It's only logical, because how would it be able to know from which table a CTE.columnname to take when there's 2.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the `ON` clause. It is in the `SELECT`. Using `*` selects both `t1.id` and `t2.id`. These two have the same name, hence the error that you get.

The only work-around I can see is to apply `*` to the table having the largest number of columns, and explicitly name the columns of the other table that you want to select:

```
WITH t12 AS (
   SELECT t1.*, t2.myColumn, etc...  
   FROM t1 
   INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
)
SELECT * FROM t12
```

Comment: And then use a script to list the columns of the second table so that you don't have to type them in

Comment: If `t1` has a column named `myColumn` then it would still fail (with different column but same problem).

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci This shouldn't be a problem, since the columns of the other table are *explicitly* specified. I've explained where the issue with the name conflict is, so it is clear enough that all columns with the same names should be omitted.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos But one could mention that if you need to select columns with the same name from the second table that you could alias them.  Especially if Peter Smith's suggestion is used. Although that's pretty much obvious to most, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a subquery (CTE or regular subquery) with 2 or more columns with the exact same name. There is no workaround unfortunately. Your only option is explicitly changing repeated columns alias as you select them, either doing it manually or by dynamic SQL.